# Disk Management - Merge nonsequential partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have this partition schema on Windows:

[image]

My problem is that after installing Windows 8.1 that 350MB Recover Partition appeared in between the C:\ Drive and my 100GB free space. Is it possible to "move" (copy) everything in the 350MB partition to the end of the free space, so I can merge C:\ with 100GB Free Space?

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be not direct answer, but you have possibility to

1. format and assign a drive letter to this free partition
2. attach it to any empty folder on C: drive (using `diskmgmt.msc`). This would give you more space on C: but it does not answer exactly your question. I write it as a possibility.

To swap these partitons you would have to:

1. move recovery partiton data to next partition (boot sector also? don't know recovery partiton enough but it would be needed to move more than files only - see below - make image)
2. shrink the beginning of the next partition using [GParted](http://gparted.org/) so that it would have 350MB of size (there will be empty space after that)
3. resize (extend) the C: drive

GParted processing partitions would take long time (hours).

Safe option is to make image of the recovery partition, change partitions and restore the image to the new place.

Please remember to `chkdsk /f` all available partitions prior to GParted changes!